# Formatting/creating file system on multipath volume for ZFS on Linux?

Tags: centos, zfs, zfsonlinux, multipath

I inherited a ZFS on Linux (CentOS) storage pool and I have a faulty multipath device (`mpathah`) in my pool:

```
      raidz3-6   DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ...
        ...
        mpathba  ONLINE       0     0     0
        mpathbb  ONLINE       0     0     0
        mpathbc  ONLINE       0     0     0
        mpathah  FAULTED      ...
```

I've loosely followed the [Solaris ZFS instructions on replacing a faulty disk](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gazgd/index.html) and swapped out the disk. It seems `multipathd` automatically picks up the new disk and assigns it `mpathcn`, so now I try to replace the old device but get the following error:

```
$ zpool replace mypool mpathah mpathcn
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/mapper/mpathcn contains a filesystem of type 'vfat'
```

Indeed it seems the rest of the multipath devices on this vdev are formatted differently:

```
$ blkid /dev/mapper/mpathcn
/dev/mapper/mpathcn: LABEL="HDD" UUID="xxxx-xxxx" TYPE="vfat"

$ blkid /dev/mapper/mpathbc
/dev/mapper/mpathbc: LABEL="mypool" UUID="xxxx" UUID_SUB="xxxx" TYPE="zfs_member"
```

What's the right way to do this? I found a [similar previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/706132/create-file-system-on-multipath-volume) - is this correct?

```
$ pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpathcn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your new virtual disk had a VFAT filesystem on it and was not erased before you reused it.

It's safe to use it with `zpool replace -f` but this will destroy any old data on the disk, as ZFS will begin resilvering immediately.